# I'm trying to read a .csv file into my sas terminal but it will only display the first row of observations

Tags: csv, sas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ric7x.png)I'm reading a .csv file into my sas terminal using infile, but for some reason it will not display anything past my first row of observations. Here is my code:

```
data fines;
        infile '/home/scf-09/ianscott/Acct493/Project/dataset1.csv'
                firstobs = 1
                truncover DSD
        ;
        length
                Parent $15
                Year $4
                Penalty $11
                Subtraction $10
                Net $11
                Agency $20
                Primary $20
                Secondary $20
                Country $15
                Industry $20
        ;
informat Parent Year Penalty Subtraction Net Agency Primary Secondary Country Industry 10.;
        input
                Parent $
                Year
                Penalty
                Subtraction
                Net
                Agency $
                Primary $
                Secondary $
                Country $
                Industry $;
run;

proc print data=fines(obs=5);
        title 'fines data';
run;




1 Bank of America 2011 20000000 0 20000000 Justice Department C mortgage abuses Servicemembers Civil USA financial services
```

Answer (score 1):

```
infile '/home/scf-09/ianscott/Acct493/Project/dataset1.csv'
            firstobs = 1
            truncover DSD
    ;
```

The first thing I look at when having this kind of issue is whether the file has the same line terminator as what your OS expects.  If your SAS runs on Unix, and the file's in Excel here so it's probably on Windows, for example, then you have `0A` line terminator; that's usually the opposite problem if anything, though.  If you're going the other way around - the CSV was created in Unix but you're in Windows - then it won't see any line terminators.  You might need `TERMSTR` option to the appropriate terminator.

I see `/` slashes (unix-style), so that makes me think this is very likely the issue. Try adding `TERMSTR=LF` to your infile.

Comment: DSD should include DLM=',', doesn't it?

Comment: @ but it's in the docs! Isn't that your favourite bed time reading material? `The DSD option changes how SAS treats delimiters when you use LIST input and sets the default delimiter to a comma`

Answer (score 1):

If you created the CSV file using Excel on a MAC then it has a nasty habit of using CR (`'0D'x`) as the end of line character.  Apparently Excel never got the message that MacOS is now based on Unix and so uses LF (`'0A'x`) as the end of line character and not CR like the original MacOS did back in the 1980's.

You should be able to pick a different file type when you save it to make it NOT do that.

You can tell SAS how to read a file that is using just CR as the end of line marker by adding the `TERMSTR=` option to the `INFILE` statement.

```
infile '/home/scf-09/ianscott/Acct493/Project/dataset1.csv'
  firstobs = 1 
  termstr=CR
  truncover 
  DSD
;
```